# Multiple posts in a column with different heights, multi-column layout

Tags: html, css, grid

I am currently making a blog layout, and I have my posts contained in divs and currently my blog posts show as following:

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of whitespace when one item in the column has a greater height than the other.

How I want it to look like is:

[image]

What would be the best way to do this? As I am currently using Bourbon Neat's grid system to make my grid for the blog layout.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code to see what you've done.

Comment: Search for *Masonry* here

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the best way is to use a two-column table that can contain posts.

Something like this[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 `column-count` should do what you are looking for [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts)

```
   -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
```

The order in which it displays children is from top to bottom so for example: child 1 and 2 would be in the first column then child 3 and 4 in the second [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2YZzm/).